# Canvas drawing with gradient fill and curvy shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, draw, curve

My question title seems common.. but this is different from other question.. I have tried many solutions but not able to get perfect solution yet. Also not able to understand draw functions.

This is what I have tried so far :

```
public class DrawingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawing);

        ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);


        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                1000, // Width
                300, // Height
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 // Config
        );

        // Initialize a new Canvas instance
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        // Draw a solid color on the canvas as background
        canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        // Initialize a new Paint instance to draw the line
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        // Line color
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        // Line width in pixels
        paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);


        final RectF oval = new RectF();

        // Set a pixels value to offset the line from canvas edge
        int offset = 0;

        canvas.drawLine(
                offset, // startX
                canvas.getHeight() / 2, // startY
                300, // stopX
                canvas.getHeight() / 2, // stopY
                paint // Paint
        );


        oval.set(250, 100, 300,200);

        canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, -(float) 90, false,paint);


        oval.set(450, 300, 500,350);

        canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, -(float) 90, false,paint);

        canvas.drawLine(
                300, // startX
                canvas.getHeight() -50, // startY
                1000, // stopX
                canvas.getHeight() -50, // stopY
                paint // Paint
        );

        // Display the newly created bitmap on app interface
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

*My output :*

[image]

**So my question is :**

1. I want to draw that curvy lines as per expected output if someone can explain its points or a example code.
2. Want to know about draw arcs left,top,right,bottom points (I have read the doc but it is just telling that they are float no description for it).
3. I want to fill this shape with gradient colors only this shape not whole canvas.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: see `Canvas#drawPath`

Comment: @pskink Sorry but could you please explain with some code if possible.. as i am trying this so far and not getting any results :(

Comment: so post your code using `Path` objects

Comment: @pskink I have tried canvas first time so don't know about path and don't know how to use that.. I will try to read the docs and get back to you

Comment: @pskink yes i have read about drawPath but it require path object and what that object will contain that i don't understand.. and it is for filling color so what about drawing that curvy line?

Comment: then read `Path` documentation - it has many methods to shape your path

Comment: see [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/D0wLE0HQ) for example

Comment: @pskink yes thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Path You can draw Bezier Path.

Check my Effort as Below.

```
 private class MyDrawView extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Path mPath;

    public MyDrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);

    }

    public MyDrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mPath = new Path();
        mPath.moveTo(200, 200);
        mPath.lineTo(200, 100);
        mPath.lineTo(600, 100);
        mPath.lineTo(600, 300);
        mPath.lineTo(300, 300);
        mPath.cubicTo(250, 270, 400, 170, 200, 200);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

initialize this custom view and add in your frame-layout. Like,

```
 MyDrawView myDrawView = new MyDrawView(this);
 frmCustom.addView(myDrawView);
```

Comment: Can you tell me one thing that how to use this class in activity? i mean just need to create object?

Comment: and use this in mydrawview class for gradient color.

`protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0 ,0 ,w, h, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
        }`

Comment: hey i want to ask one more thing i want to add same shape below this shape which just look like shadow to this... so do i need to adjust dy in moveTo? or any suggestion please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172158/discussion-between-abk-and-annie).